# What is the correct method of adding a link to this javascript slideshow group?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works until I add a link around the images. It works with the links removed and the 'a' between 'slideshow img' in the js and css removed.

## In Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow a img.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow a img:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow a img:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');
$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
var $first = $('#slideshow a img:first');
    $first.addClass('active');    
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 4500 );
});

</script>
```

## In Body:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <a href="/samplehome"><img src="/img/slide_three.jpg" width="948px" height="432px" border="0" alt="Three"/></a>
   <a href="/samplehome"><img src="/img/slide_two.jpg" width="948px" height="432px" border="0" alt="Two"/></a>
   <a href="/samplehome"><img src="/img/slide_one.jpg" width="948px" height="432px" border="0" alt="Ease In Motion"/></a>
</div>
```

## In CSS:

```
#slideshow, #sub_slideshow {
position:relative;
height:432px;
width: 948px;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: right;
}

#slideshow a img, #sub_slideshow a img {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:8;
opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow a img.active, #sub_slideshow a img.active {
z-index:10;
opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow a img.last-active , #sub_slideshow a img.last-active {
z-index:9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code and it worked. It got error because your jquery selector wasn't right.

Change this line

```
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow a img:first');
```

to this

```
 var $next =  $active.parent().next().children("img").length ? $active.parent().next().children("img")
        : $('#slideshow a img:first');
```

Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 1):

.next() retrieves the next sibling in the page, not the next item within the jQuery set returned by your original call and not the next `<a>` link in your page.  You cam just iterate through the jQuery set (like you would iterate though an array) or use .each() rather than use next() or you can use Black Ship's method to follow the DOM hieararchy.

Comment: Thank you for your input here. It seems to be working with .next() after I made Black Ships suggested change, do you recommend that I change it to .each()?

Comment: Black Ship's recommendation works fine for what you are trying to do.